# Jenkins multibranch pipeline post build actions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to define post build actions for Jenkins multi pipeline project?

There is a separate option available when you have a simple project but not for multipipeline.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add post build steps to a Multibranch Pipeline, you need to code these steps into the `finally` block, an example is below:

```
node {

    try {
        stage("Checkout") {
            // checkout scm
        }

        stage("Build & test") {
            // build & Unit test
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // fail the build if an exception is thrown
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
        throw e
    } finally {
        // Post build steps here
        /* Success or failure, always run post build steps */
        // send email
        // publish test results etc etc
    }
}
```

For most of the post-build steps you would want there are online examples of them on how to write in pipeline format. If you have any specific one please list it here

Comment: I'm trying to use the [Artifact Deployer plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifactdeployer/) but there is no declarative pipeline documentation and I can't find any examples online.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a pipeline, you describe the whole flow yourself, which gives you great flexibility to do whatever you want, including running post-build steps.

You can see an example of using post-build steps in a pipeline I wrote:

https://github.com/geek-kb/Android_Pipeline/blob/master/Jenkinsfile

Example from that code:

```
run_in_stage('Post steps', {
    sh """
        # Add libCore.so files to symbols.zip
        find ${cwd}/Product-CoreSDK/obj/local -name libCore.so | zip -r ${cwd}/Product/build/outputs/symbols.zip -@
        # Remove unaligned apk's
        rm -f ${cwd}/Product/build/outputs/apk/*-unaligned.apk
    """
})
```